Why are two CFA models not equivalent if I drop some variables from my dataframe or restrict factor loadings to 0, keeping all variables? lavaan
Exploring nested vs. non-nested models, I was surprised with a strange result. The first model uses 21 variables from my dataframe and runs a CFA. The second model uses 28 variables from my dataframe, but restricts the factor loadings of 7 variables to 0.
mod1 <- "F1 =~ fig_1 + fig_2 + fig_3 + fig_4 + fig_6 + fig_7 + fig_10 + fig_11 + 
        fig_12 + fig_13 + fig_14 + fig_15 + fig_17 + fig_18 + fig_19 + fig_20 +
        fig_21 + fig_22 + fig_24 + fig_25 + fig_28"

mod2 <- "F1 =~ fig_1 + fig_2 + fig_3 + fig_4 + fig_6 + fig_7 + fig_10 + fig_11 + 
        fig_12 + fig_13 + fig_14 + fig_15 + fig_17 + fig_18 + fig_19 + fig_20 +
        fig_21 + fig_22 + fig_24 + fig_25 + fig_28 +
        0*fig_26 + 0*fig_23 + 0*fig_8 + 0*fig_9 + 0*fig_5 + 0*fig_16 + 0*fig_27"

These two CFA models are
cfa1 <- cfa(mod1 ,
data = df_mig %>%
select(fig_1:fig_28) %>%
select(-c(fig_26, fig_23, fig_8, fig_9,
fig_5, fig_16, fig_27)),
estimator = 'WLSM',
ordered=TRUE)
cfa2 <- cfa(mod2 ,
data = df_mig %>%
select(fig_1:fig_28), #using all columns
estimator = 'WLSM',
ordered=TRUE)
Factor loadings are all the same, but model fit are way different.

any ideas?


Factor loadings are all the same, but model fit are way different

That is because you are fitting the models to different data sets.

When you fit the SEM to all 28 variables, its fit is based on a $28 \times 28$ model-implied polychoric correlation matrix (compared to an analogous polychoric correlation matrix from a saturated model)
When you fit the SEM to only 21 variables, its fit is based on a $21 \times 21$ model-implied polychoric correlation matrix

That is why your $df$ differ so wildly: the SEM with 28 variables makes many restrictions (that the additional 7 variables are uncorrelated with each other or any of the 21 indicators of the factor) that the 21-variable SEM does not make.

The parameter difference is 7 between the models  ... It may be that lavaan makes you estimate thresholds

The 7 additional parameters are the thresholds for the 7 additional variables (they must be binary, so 1 threshold per additional variable).  But that does not affect the $df$ or fit because they are also estimated in the saturated model.  That is, there are 7 additional sample statistics (thresholds used to estimate polychoric correlations), compensated by estimating those same 7 thresholds in the CFA.

Amazing. Just two follow-up quest: Is it possible to get the same results if I adapt this code "F1 =~ fig_1 + fig_2 + fig_3 + fig_4 + fig_6 + fig_7 + fig_10 + fig_11 + fig_12 + fig_13 + fig_14 + fig_15 + fig_17 + fig_18 + fig_19 + fig_20 +fig_21 + fig_22 + fig_24 + fig_25 + fig_28 + 0*fig_26 + 0*fig_23 + 0*fig_8 + 0*fig_9 + 0*fig_5 + 0*fig_16 + 0*fig_27" or if I use a bigger df this always impact the results?
Second: Would you consider this 21-item CFA nested into the 28-item model? -- This question I was originally thinking about—I was comparing these models with AIC and BIC. Thanks

(1)  The model-fit statistic is answer a different research question when you use the same parameter estimates to reproduce different data.  (2) The models are not nested because they are not fitted to the same data.  There is no statistically comparing models fitted to different data.   You could compare a CFA with 21 free loadings to one with 28 free loadings, as long as you fit both models to all 28 indicators (the one with fixed 0 loadings is nested in the one with all 28 loadings free).

Thank you so much, @Terrence. Your explanations on this topic were very informative and solid. Keep up the good work!!
